# Finding out the asp.net version for code?

Tags: asp.net

Generally, how do you figure out which version of asp.net that an app is written in? The app in question is [VP-ASP 6.5](http://www.vpasp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd just submit a request and ask.

Reading through the setup guide it looks like it is written in classic ASP and not ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct VP-ASP 6.5 is written in ASP.  In fact all version (through the current 7.0) are in ASP.  The publishers have stated that the next version will be in ASP.NET